# Can't make object method return var

Tags: javascript, loops, return

I have an object in this code with a list of methods that I want to be able to run. TS and TL are variable integers input from my site. All I want to do is make these var's store the number that results from the equation in each method. Am I misunderstanding what return does? Do I need to somehow specify that I want my loop to run through the methods? What am I doing wrong?

So everyone understands the point here. The object is being used to calculate measurements, but depending on what the user inputs in TL and TS will depend on what the equation is equal to. Afterwards I need to convert the number in each variable to a string, split() it at the decimal point, use Erik Garrison's fraction library to convert the decimal to a fraction and put the fraction back with the whole number from the original equation.

```
function Cut_Lengths (){
var SideWall_Retainer;
var EndWall_Retainer;
var SideWall_Coping;
var EndWall_Coping;
var Housing_Shells;
var Housing_Pre_Cap;
var Housing_Cap;
var Housing_Anchor_Plate;
var Housing_Bond_Beam_Plate;
var Flush_Lid;
var Flush_Lid_Fascia;


var cutLengths = {
    SWRT : function (){SideWall_Retainer = TL + 10.75; return SideWall_Retainer;},
    EWRT : function (){EndWall_Retainer = TS - .1875; return EndWall_Retainer;},
    SWCP : function (){SideWall_Coping = TL + 7.625; return SideWall_Coping;},
    EWCP : function (){EndWall_Coping = TS - .5; return EndWall_Coping;},
    NHS : function (){Housing_Shells = Math.floor((TS + 48) / 72); return Housing_Shells;},
    HPC : function (){Housing_Pre_Cap = TS + 48; return Housing_Pre_Cap},
    HC : function (){Housing_Cap = TS + 46.25; return Housing_Cap;},
    HAP : function (){Housing_Anchor_Plate = TS - .25; return Housing_Anchor_Plate;},
    HBP : function (){Housing_Bond_Beam_Plate = TS - .1875; return Housing_Bond_Beam_Plate;},
    FL : function (){Flush_Lid = TS + 13; return Flush_Lid;},
    FLF : function (){Flush_Lid_Fascia = TS - .5; return Flush_Lid_Fascia;}
};
for (var x in cutLengths){};
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting? Everything looks fine, but just... incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of your function will apply the correct calculation, depending on the values you pass for `type`, `TL` and `TS`. (you can as well omit `TL` and `TS` in the function signature, if you want to use your “outer” values.) There's no need to loop through the variables.

```
function Cut_Lengths(type, TL, TS){
    var cutLengths = {
        SWRT : function (){ return TL + 10.75; },
        EWRT : function (){ return TS - .1875; },
        SWCP : function (){ return TL + 7.625; },
        EWCP : function (){ return TS - .5; },
        NHS : function (){ return Math.floor((TS + 48) / 72); },
        HPC : function (){ return TS + 48; },
        HC : function (){ return TS + 46.25; },
        HAP : function (){ return TS - .25; },
        HBP : function (){ return TS - .1875; },
        FL : function (){ return TS + 13; },
        FLF : function (){ return TS - .5; }
    };
    return cutLengths[type]();
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you. Would you mind explaining why the return in my original function didn't work? What was it about what I was doing that was wrong?

Comment: There is no `return` at all. ;) Although the functions of the `cutLength` object would return something, *(a)* they are never invoked, and *(b)* the `Cut_Lengths()` function itself doesn't do anything at all (except for the empty loop).

Comment: Should be `return cutLengths[type]();` to get a result.

Comment: Make sure you place a `0` in front of decimals in JavaScript.

Comment: @ PHPglue: Wow, So much good info here. Thanks for the tip on 0 decimals. And for all your help with the comment below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute each function in a loop it's like:

```
for(var i in cutLengths){
  // i is property like SWRT -> cutLengths[i] is value which is method in your case
  var revolvingVariable = cutLengths[i]();
}
```

Now at each step of the loop `revolvingVariable` is the return value of the function at that step of the loop. I think you want to use a Constructor, though:

```
function CutLengths(TL, TS){
  // you can leave out arguments if you want
  this.currentTL = TL ? TL : 1; // change 1 to default
  this.currentTS = TS ? TS : 1; // change 1 to default
  this.end_wall_container_value;
  this.side_wall_retainer = function(){
    return this.currentTL + 10.75;
  }
  /* The keyword `this` refers to the Object or current instance created with
    the keyword `new` outside of `this` Constructor, `CutLengths`.
    Must be a method since `this.currentTS` could change and a property gets
    it's value when you assign it.
  */
  this.end_wall_container = function(set){
    if(set){
      this.end_wall_container_value = set;
      return set;
    }
    var ts = this.currentTS - 0.1875;
    this.end_wall_container_value = ts;
    return ts; 
  }
  this.side_wall_coping = function(){
    return this.currentTL + 7.625;
  }
  this.end_wall_coping = function(){
    return this.currentTS - 0.5;
  }
  this.housing_shells = function(){
    return Math.floor((this.currentTS + 48) / 72);
  }
  this.housing_pre_cap = function(){
    return this.currentTS + 48;
  }
  this.housing_cap = function(){
    return this.currentTS + 46.25;
  }
  this.housing_anchor_plate = function(){
    return this.currentTS - 0.25;
  }
  this.housing_bond_beam_plate = function(){
    return this.currentTS - 0.1875;
  }
  this.flush_lid = function(){
    return this.currentTS + 13;
  }
  this.flush_lid_fascia = function(){
    return this.currentTS - 0.5;
  }
}
var cutL = new CutLengths(1, 2);
console.log(cutL.end_wall_container());
cutL.currentTL = 5;
console.log(cutL.end_wall_container());
console.log(cutL.end_wall_container(25));
console.log(cutL.end_wall_container());
var cutL_another = new CutLengths;
console.log(cutL_another.end_wall_container());
```

Comment: The comment in your loop was super helpful! Thank you very much.